# custom validation attribute for checkbox list in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I have a requirement where an aribitrary list of checkboxes are dispalyed in a form and I have to make sure atleast 1 checkbox is checked while submitting the form. I have no idea how this to be done. Can some one please explain with an example?I need client side validation also

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that may help you, [Checkbox has to be ‘checked’ – with unobtrusive jQuery validation and ASP.NET MVC 3](http://itmeze.com/2010/12/06/checkbox-has-to-be-checked-with-unobtrusive-jquery-validation-and-asp-net-mvc-3/)

You need to create a custom validation, here is an example of a single checkbox must be checked validator:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class MustBeTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return value != null && value is bool && (bool)value;
    }
}
```

Then add this attribute to the checkbox in your model, just like you would add the `[Required]` attribute:

```
[MustBeTrue(ErrorMessage = "Please accept terms and conditions before continuing")]
public bool AcceptTerms { get; set; }
```